# cleartext Javascript function does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use cleatext to clear the content in the textarea with ID "css", but it does not work, anyone knows what is wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>CSS3 Flexible Box Layout</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                function preview() {
                    var textArea = document.getElementById('html');
                    var div = document.getElementById('preview');
                    var text = textArea.value;
                    div.innerHTML = text;
                }

                function cleartext() {
                    var textareaObject = document.getElementById('css');

                    console.dir(textareaObject); 
                    textareaObject.innerHTML = "";
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="#" method="POST">
                <div id="columnsWrapper">

                    <div class="middleRow">

                        <textarea id="css" name="css" placeholder="CSS..."></textarea>
                        <br>
                        <textarea id="html" name="html" placeholder="HTML..."></textarea>

                    </div>
                    <div class="middleRow2" id="preview"></div>
                    <div id="button">
                        <br>
                        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="preview()">Launch</button>
                        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="cleartext()" >Clear</button>
                        <button type="button" class="button">Toggle</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="empty"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

also I  have tried to use textareaObject.value = null;
it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `textareaObject.value = ""`? This should probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `value` instead of `innerHTML`

```js
                function preview() {
                    var textArea = document.getElementById('html');
                    var div = document.getElementById('preview');
                    var text = textArea.value;
                    div.value = text;
                }

                function cleartext() {
                    var textareaObject = document.getElementById('css');

                    console.dir(textareaObject); 
                    textareaObject.value = "";
                }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>CSS3 Flexible Box Layout</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="#" method="POST">
                <div id="columnsWrapper">

                    <div class="middleRow">

                        <textarea id="css" name="css" placeholder="CSS..."></textarea>
                        <br>
                        <textarea id="html" name="html" placeholder="HTML..."></textarea>

                    </div>
                    <div class="middleRow2" id="preview"></div>
                    <div id="button">
                        <br>
                        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="preview()">Launch</button>
                        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="cleartext()" >Clear</button>
                        <button type="button" class="button">Toggle</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="empty"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/4PWSzqItL55DqhVQV4PC?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>CSS3 Flexible Box Layout</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                function preview() {
                    var textArea = document.getElementById('html');
                    var div = document.getElementById('preview');
                    var text = textArea.value;
                    div.innerHTML = text;
                }

                function cleartext() {
                    var textareaObject = document.getElementById('css');

                    console.dir(textareaObject); 
                    textareaObject.value = "";
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="#" method="POST">
                <div id="columnsWrapper">

                    <div class="middleRow">

                        <textarea id="css" name="css" placeholder="CSS..."></textarea>
                        <br>
                        <textarea id="html" name="html" placeholder="HTML..."></textarea>

                    </div>
                    <div class="middleRow2" id="preview"></div>
                    <div id="button">
                        <br>
                        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="preview()">Launch</button>
                        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="cleartext()" >Clear</button>
                        <button type="button" class="button">Toggle</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="empty"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```